# How I can disable item property after leave current data block? Oracle Forms

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, oracleforms

I there!Im coding a simple master-detail form to practice Oracle Forms technology and now I am stacked in a problem when I pass inside blocks. I've created a non-database item to show department name instead of department id but when I would like insert a new record, I need to insert department id in table (Simple HR schema) but when I go to previous block I receive a alrrt about save changes. What is the problem? I think that I can fix this problem if I can disable validate lov property after leave employees data block but How Can I do it? Do you have any idea??? Thanks!!!

[image]

After I leave "Employees" data block and I click into "Jobs" frame I receive this alert about save changes.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you create a detail record, you should COMMIT those changes.

Because, once you navigate to a **different** master record, Forms' triggers/procedures will perform a new Execute Query operation on the detail block, which means that changes you've made (i.e. newly added record) will be lost. That's why Forms politely asks you whether you'd want to save those changes or not.